# Camtasia complains about "insufficient space on disk" even though I have a few GBs available on all partitions. Why?

Tags: windows, camtasia

I have a few GBs available on all partitions:

[image]

When recording with TechSmith Camtasia 8.3.0, I get the error message:

[image]

which prevents me from further recording.

The temporary folder is on `C`:

[image]

Why is Camtasia complaining about "insufficient space on disk"? (e.g., is there some setting on the minimum available space that should remain?)

I use TechSmith Camtasia 8.3.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: At a guess, it's to prevent filling the HDD so completely that essential OS files (e.g. pagefile.sys) cannot be created or modified. Why not clean up the disks? The C:\ system disk, in particular, is more than 99% full, likely to soon crash.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what do you mean by the system disk is likely to soon crash?

Comment: Once the OS cannot write files, because the disk is too full, you will not be able to delete the files easily, because the PC can no longer boot. (The files could then be deleted by booting from live media with WinPE, but that would be problematic for someone with no experience.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik there is 7GB of available space, that's quite some margin.

Comment: Download process monitor from Sysinternals (Microsoft) and capture a trace of what Camtasia is doing. If you can share the trace, I'm curious enough to have a look at it ;) *(no guarantees of any solution offcourse)*

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Pagefile may be ~1.5 x RAM.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - It isn't enough of a margin in a case like this.  Have you considered using a more recent version of the application?  My research indicates this problem is directly connected to the fact, your disk is nearly full, the only other possible explanation is you have quotas configured.

Comment: You can always continue using the current version, but change the location of the temporary file (which typically requires twice as much space, as the recording requires).  Which means a 50 MB recording will require 100 MB, until you stop the recording, unclear how large the recording your attempting to make is. It would help if your question contained some of that information.

Comment: [It could also be with your chosen video codec](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/my_longer_recordings_are_getting_stopped_because_camtasia_recorder_thinks_it_is_out_of_space), if that is the issue, update your question with the relevant information.